# What does the phrase "You don't say" represent?

Tags: meaning, phrases

In an English movie, Marianne and Bob were talking to each other:

> **Marianne:** "Joy went to Jordan last week to search for religious sites."
>
> **Bob:** "You don't say?"

My question is: What does Bob's reply mean here?
 Was he angry to hear this about Joe or was he surprised to know that Joe went to Jordan?

Comment: I'd like to mention that it is also a very [popular meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-dont-say) involving Nicolas Cage! I came to know about the phrase through the meme.

Comment: "You don't say! ... You don't say! ... You don't say!"  "Well, what's going on?" "He didn't say"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"You don't say?"**

> informal
>
> 1. used to express amazement or disbelief.
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=You+don%27t+say&oq=You+don%27t+say&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Bob could have easily have simply said, "really?"

Comment: thanks for the reply. When someone , say You are talking to me. You : "Starkeen! The world is going to end by 2099." Starkeen : "You don't say.? World will never end ". Does it make sense to append another sentence to this phrase?

Comment: Appending a contradictory sentence right after it is a little jarring.  An introductory phrase might help.  "You don't say?  I think the world will never end".  Helps transition from disbelief to contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

*You don't say* is an idiom and can mean several things depending on context.
Could range from sarcasm or irony to mild surprise or amazement. The hearers usually have to supply the interpretation for themselves.

> How surprising, is that true? Also, I find that hard to believe. For
>   example, I've been working on this project for two years.-You don't
>   say, or The man who runs this soup kitchen is a real saint.-You don't
>   say! This expression, a shortening of you don't say so, may be used
>   straightforwardly or ironically. [Late 1800s]
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.
>   Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by
>   Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Comment: Wait, sarcasm and irony would mean the same here.  And you can use them on any idiom.